# How to get a <td> 's position in a table using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

For example:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1,1</td><td>2,1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2,1</td><td>2,2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to using the following function:

```
$("td").click(function(){
alert(xxxx)
})
```

to get the `<td>` `s position when clicked, but how?

Answer (score 24):

The `index` function called with no parameters will get the position relative to its siblings (no need to traverse the hierarchy).

```
$('td').click(function(){   
   var $this = $(this);
   var col   = $this.index();
   var row   = $this.closest('tr').index();

   alert( [col,row].join(',') );
});
```

Answer (score 16):

[Core / index](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index)

```
$("td").click(function(){

    var column = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index(this.parentNode);

    alert([column, ',', row].join(''));
})
```

Answer (score 8):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775466/how-to-get-cells-td-x-and-y-coordinate-in-table-using-jquery), DOM Level 2 exposes [`cellIndex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-80748363) and [`rowIndex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67347567) properties of `td` and `tr` elements, respectively.

Lets you do this, which is pretty readable:

```
$("td").click(function(){

    var column = this.cellIndex;
    var row = $(this).parentNode.rowIndex;

    alert("[" + column + ", " + row + "]");
});
```

Comment: this code won't actually work as-is since you're calling `cellIndex` on a jQuery object, just use `this.cellIndex` instead of `$(this).cellIndex`, same with getting the row

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery 1.6 :

```
$(this).prop('cellIndex')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("td").click(function(e){
  alert(e.target.parentElement.rowIndex + " " + e.target.cellIndex)
});
```

```css
tr, td {
  padding: 0.3rem;
  border: 1px solid black
}

table:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0, 0</td>
    <td>0, 1</td>
    <td>0, 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1, 0</td>
    <td>1, 1</td>
    <td>1, 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```