# How to get cells (<td>) x and y coordinate in table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates

I'm looking for a good way to get cells X-Y position in a table. (do not confuse it with css-position, I am looking for X and Y coordinate in Cartesian coordinate system).

As we know, we can get particular cell in a table using ex: `$('#grid')[0].rows[5].cells[7]`.

But, what if I want to get the value `5x7` when I click on particular cell, i.e:

```
$('#grid td').click(function(){
   alert("My position in table is: " + myPosition.X + "x" + myPosition.Y);
});
```

I guess, the easiest way is to add innerHTML, ID or CSS class to every cell (`<td class="p-5x7">` etc.) when creating table in back end, then parse it, and return on click, but is there any way to get these coordinates based purely on DOM?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

DOM Level 2 HTML [cellIndex](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-80748363):

```
alert('My position in table is: '+this.cellIndex+'x'+this.parentNode.rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert("My position in table is: " + e.target.parentElement.rowIndex + "x " + e.target.cellIndex + "y");
  }, false);
}
```

```css
tr, td {
  padding: 0.6rem;
  border: 1px solid black
}

table:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="grid">
  <tr>
    <td>0, 0</td>
    <td>0, 1</td>
    <td>0, 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1, 0</td>
    <td>1, 1</td>
    <td>1, 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```