# Getting coordinates of table cells and comparing with different tables via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's really easy to access to coordinates of `table` `cell`s with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999018/5417479) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1775509/5417479) example ways. But when I'm trying to get `cell`s and compare with another `table`'s `cell` which is avaible on page, a problem occurs. Because I don't know how to compare them in same time. After many hours I tried to do this, unfortunately, still there is no luck.

In following classic `table`s list below, shows 2 different `table`s with different `id` numbers:

```
    <table id="a1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>RED</td>
                <td>GREEN</td>
                <td>BLUE</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>YELLOW</td>
                <td>PINK</td>
                <td>samespothere</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<hr>
    <table id="a2">
       <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>BLACK</td>
                <td>BROWN</td>
                <td>WHITE</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>CYAN</td>
                <td>GRAY</td>
                <td>samespothereANDsomeextra</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And also, I'm using modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999018/5417479) `JS` example to get location of `cell`s. This modified version I did is not able to make compare operation. I've just edited for make it easier.

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");  //For all table cells on page.

var i;
for(i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{

    cells[i].onclick = vera;
}

function vera()
{
        var cellIndex  = this.cellIndex + 1;  

        var rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex + 1;

        var centra = cellIndex +","+ rowIndex;  //This gives the coordinate of cell which you clicked on.  

        alert(centra);

}
```

Here is my question: I need to make a compare operation when I click on `samespothere`(Example `text` I wrote) `table` `cell`. Compare operation should be able with the same location of other `table`. Lets think like this: If second `table` `cell`(same location, different `table`) includes some of clicked `cell`'s text(from first table),  alert must show up and say "This clicked text in `table id=1 cell:2row:2`, matched in `table id=2 cell:2row:2`".

And here is the online code: http://jsfiddle.net/LujydnaL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
function vera()
{
    var cellIndex  = this.cellIndex + 1;  

    var rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex + 1; 

    var centra = cellIndex +","+ rowIndex; //This gives the coordinate of cell which you clicked on.

    alert(centra);

    // new code here
    table2 = document.getElementById('a2');
    rowInTable2 = table2.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowIndex-1];
    cellInTable2 = rowInTable2.getElementsByTagName('td')[cellIndex-1];
    console.log(cellInTable2);
    // do something with cellInTable2 now
}
```

Comment: By the way, this is tagged `jquery`, but there's no jquery in the original, so I haven't used it in the answer. With jquery, you can do most of this much more efficiently.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. I've just tried it. And it worked great. If you have a time, it would be good to show jquery method to people who is going to search something like this I think. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].addEventListener('click', function(element) {
    var rowIndex = element.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
    var cellIndex = element.target.cellIndex;
    
    var compare = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1].rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex];
    
    var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll("td");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
      myNodelist[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    
    compare.style.backgroundColor = "grey";    
    
    document.getElementById('alert1').innerHTML = ('CLICK => Row index = ' + rowIndex + ', Column index = ' + cellIndex);
    document.getElementById('alert2').innerHTML = ('COMPARE = ' + compare.innerHTML)
 }, false);
}
```

```css
tr, th, td {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  border: 1px solid black
}

table:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>a11</td>
                <td>a12</td>
                <td>a13</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>a21</td>
                <td>a22</td>
                <td>a23</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<p id="alert1"></p>    
<hr>
    <table>
       <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>b11</td>
                <td>b12</td>
                <td>b13</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>b21</td>
                <td>b22</td>
                <td>b23</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<p id="alert2"></p>
```