# Ignore click on right-most cell

Tags: jquery

I've used the code below for making a Table in which the user can click on a row to navigate to a new page. Assuming each row contains 10 cells, is there any way to alter the code so that clicking anywhere on the row APART FROM the right-most cell (10th cell) triggers the navigation?

```
$(function ()
{
 $('#link-table tr').click(function ()
 {
  location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');
 });
});
```

Comment: Are you in control of generating the markup?

Comment: Yes there is. It involves changing the selector for what gets the `click` event handler applied to a `td` and using the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) or [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415355/how-to-get-a-td-s-position-in-a-table-using-jquery) use `cellIndex` and `rowIndex` to get the specific positions with-in the table, then write your click function not to redirect when at the undesirable rows or coloumns.

```
$(function ()
{
 $('#link-table tr').click(function ()
 {
    var column = this.cellIndex;
    var row = $(this).parentNode.rowIndex;
    if( row != 7) // don't allow clicks on 7
        location.href = $(this).find('td a').attr('href');
 });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just close this as a duplicate of that other "thread"?

Comment: I was thinking doing that, but though the extra question about redirection would make it not quite a duplicate

Comment: Slight problem. The code doesn't work with `#like-table tr` however it does work with `#like-table td`, but then the line starting `location.href...` navigates to "undefined" rather than to the desired page

Comment: The solution was `if( column != 7) location.href = $('#link-table tr').find('td a').attr('href');`